# Query checking if record's date is not first or last in a selection of records

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a hard time figuring out a query I need to create.

So my table has an id and date (as int)

Example:

```
ID   EMP_ID   DATE
1    555      43507
2    555      43513
3    555      43518
4    555      43500
```

I need to return if record with given ID has records bigger and smaller than him (check if the record is not with first or last Date).

My query for now is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
   INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table
        where ID = @id 
    ) x ON x.EMP_ID = t.EMP_ID
HAVING COUNT (x.DATE < t.DATE) > 1
    AND COUNT(x.DATE> t.DATE) > 1
```

But obviously COUNT doesn't work that way and I get "Incorrect syntax" error.
What is the correct and shortest way to achieve this.

I know that it is possible to do it with two different SELECT queries with COUNT(*) and WHERE but I don't think this is the best possible solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? This is far easier with 2012+.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *are* on SQL Server 2012, you can use Window Functions:

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1;

WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT*
    FROM (VALUES(1,555,43507),
                (2,555,43513),
                (3,555,43518),
                (4,555,43500)) V(ID,EMP_ID,[DATE])),
CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           EMP_ID,
           [DATE],
           COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY [DATE]
                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS BackCount,
           COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY [DATE]
                           ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS ForwardCount
    FROM VTE)
SELECT ID,
       EMP_ID,
       [DATE]
FROM CTE
WHERE ID = @ID
  AND BackCount > 0
  AND ForwardCount > 0;
```

There's no need for 3 scans of the table this way. of course, if you're still on SQL Server 2008, you can't use this (but you really should be looking at upgrading if you are, as it's so close to End of Life).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get it with two subqueries :

```
select *
from table t1
where exists (select * 
              from table t2 
              where t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id and 
                    t2.date < t1.date)
       and
       exists (select * 
               from table t2 
               where t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id and 
                     t2.date > t1.date)
```

PS: By the way, the count that you wanted to make :

```
COUNT(x.DATE < t.DATE) > 1
```

is done like this :

```
sum(case when x.DATE < t.DATE then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's call it "*testable*". Then below query will return rows if your criteria matches

```
SELECT DISTINCT et.*
FROM testtable et
JOIN testtable gt ON et.id<>gt.id
JOIN testtable lt ON et.id<>gt.id
WHERE et.id = @id
AND et.empdate < gt.empdate
AND et.empdate > lt.empdate
```